# MVC5 Identity "Invalid Token"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I realize that there are a few questions about the "Invalid Token" message and I have read them, they mostly deal with different assemblies/urlencode.

However I try to do this:

```
var token = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user.Id, token);
```

And the result is always "Invalid Token", and I have no idea what could be going on since it even is the same freakin object that fails to validate the token it just created. I am using a mostly vanilla MVC project template. The user in question was added directly using the ApplicationContext's `Initializer.Seed()`, is that a problem?

This is the vanilla code that sets up the provider:

```
var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("blah"));
}
```